# runtime:unexpected return pc for runtime.gopark called from0x0

Tags: go

I wrote a go project, which is used to wrap the access to ETCD and provide interface to C language for use, https://github.com/dingrui37/etcdagent, (sorry for my poor English)
[image: compile]
After finishing the test of this project, I build it to a shared library:
`go build -buildmode=c-shared -o cgo/libetcd.so main.go`
But when running, it **sometimes** gives an exception as follows, can someone give me a help?

```
[NewThread0x7fff9a7fc700(LWP1615)]
runtime:unexpectedreturnpcforruntime.goparkcalledfrom0x0
stack:frame={sp:0xc000062f90,fp:0xc000062fb0}stack=[0xc000062800,0xc000063000)
000000c000062e90:00000000000000000000000000000000
000000c000062ea0:00000000000000000000000000000000
000000c000062eb0:00000000000000000000000000000000
000000c000062ec0:00000000000000000000000000000000
000000c000062ed0:00000000000000000000000000000000
000000c000062ee0:00000000000000000000000000000000
000000c000062ef0:00000000000000000000000000000000
000000c000062f00:00000000000000000000000000000000
000000c000062f10:00000000000000000000000000000000
000000c000062f20:00000000000000000000000000000000
000000c000062f30:00000000000000000000000000000000
000000c000062f40:00000000000000000000000000000000
000000c000062f50:00000000000000000000000000000000
000000c000062f60:00000000000000000000000000000000
000000c000062f70:00000000000000000000000000000000
000000c000062f80:00000000000000000000000000000000
000000c000062f90:<00000000000000000000000000000000
000000c000062fa0:0000000000000000!0000000000000000
000000c000062fb0:>00000000000000000000000000000000
000000c000062fc0:00000000000000000000000000000000
000000c000062fd0:0000000000000000000000000106e371<runtime.goexit+1>
000000c000062fe0:00000000000000000000000000000000
000000c000062ff0:00000000000000000000000000000000
fatalerror:unknowncallerpc
runtimestack:
runtime.throw(0x1d15977,0x11)
/usr/local/go/src/runtime/panic.go:774+0x74
runtime.gentraceback(0xffffffffffffffff,0xffffffffffffffff,0x0,0xc000000a80,0x0,
0x0,0x7fffffff,0x7fff9affb3c8,0x0,0x0,...)
/usr/local/go/src/runtime/traceback.go:273+0x19e9
runtime.scanstack(0xc000000a80,0xc000043270)
/usr/local/go/src/runtime/mgcmark.go:711+0x161
runtime.scang(0xc000000a80,0xc000043270)
/usr/local/go/src/runtime/proc.go:886+0x1e5
runtime.markroot.func1()
/usr/local/go/src/runtime/mgcmark.go:221+0x71
runtime.markroot(0xc000043270,0xc000000007)
/usr/local/go/src/runtime/mgcmark.go:202+0x2f5
runtime.gcDrain(0xc000043270,0x2)
/usr/local/go/src/runtime/mgcmark.go:915+0x114
runtime.gcBgMarkWorker.func2()
/usr/local/go/src/runtime/mgc.go:1923+0x122
runtime.systemstack(0x0)
/usr/local/go/src/runtime/asm_amd64.s:370+0x63
runtime.mstart()
/usr/local/go/src/runtime/proc.go:1146
goroutine220[GCworker(idle)]:
runtime.systemstack_switch()
/usr/local/go/src/runtime/asm_amd64.s:330fp=0xc00033f760sp=0xc00033f758
pc=0x106c270
runtime.gcBgMarkWorker(0xc000042000)
/usr/local/go/src/runtime/mgc.go:1891+0x1c5fp=0xc00033f7d8
sp=0xc00033f760pc=0x102ee15
runtime.goexit()
/usr/local/go/src/runtime/asm_amd64.s:1357+0x1fp=0xc00033f7e0
sp=0xc00033f7d8pc=0x106e371
createdbyruntime.gcBgMarkStartWorkers
/usr/local/go/src/runtime/mgc.go:1785+0x79
goroutine4[syscall]:
os/signal.signal_recv(0x0)
/usr/local/go/src/runtime/sigqueue.go:147+0x9e
os/signal.loop()
/usr/local/go/src/os/signal/signal_unix.go:23+0x24
createdbyos/signal.init.0
/usr/local/go/src/os/signal/signal_unix.go:29+0x43
goroutine36[select]:
google.golang.org/grpc.(*ccBalancerWrapper).watcher(0xc000176280)
/home/dingrui/go/pkg/mod/google.golang.org/grpc@v1.24.0/balancer_conn_wrappers.go:
115+0x12e
createdbygoogle.golang.org/grpc.newCCBalancerWrapper
/home/dingrui/go/pkg/mod/google.golang.org/grpc@v1.24.0/balancer_conn_wrappers.go:
106+0x16b
goroutine44[select]:
google.golang.org/grpc/internal/transport.(*controlBuffer).get(0xc000168230,0x1,
0x0,0x0,0x0,0x0)
/home/dingrui/go/pkg/mod/google.golang.org/grpc@v1.24.0/internal/transport/control
buf.go:395+0x124
google.golang.org/grpc/internal/transport.(*loopyWriter).run(0xc000174c00,0x0,
0x0)
/home/dingrui/go/pkg/mod/google.golang.org/grpc@v1.24.0/internal/transport/control
buf.go:513+0x1e5
google.golang.org/grpc/internal/transport.newHTTP2Client.func3(0xc00026e000)
/home/dingrui/go/pkg/mod/google.golang.org/grpc@v1.24.0/internal/transport/http2_c
lient.go:338+0x7d
createdbygoogle.golang.org/grpc/internal/transport.newHTTP2Client
/home/dingrui/go/pkg/mod/google.golang.org/grpc@v1.24.0/internal/transport/http2_c
lient.go:336+0xebe
goroutine38[chanreceive]:
etcdagent/agent.(*Agent).Run(0xc000176380)
/home/dingrui/Projects/etcdagent/agent/agent.go:75+0x14e
createdbymain.EtcdAgentInit.func1
/home/dingrui/Projects/etcdagent/main.go:62+0x203
goroutine39[select]:
etcdagent/agent/event.(*event).Watch(0xc0001720a0,0x248e520,0xc000176400,
0xc000174600)
/home/dingrui/Projects/etcdagent/agent/event/event.go:45+0x408
createdbyetcdagent/agent.(*Agent).Run
/home/dingrui/Projects/etcdagent/agent/agent.go:72+0x124
goroutine20[chanreceive]:
google.golang.org/grpc.(*addrConn).resetTransport(0xc00023c000)
/home/dingrui/go/pkg/mod/google.golang.org/grpc@v1.24.0/clientconn.go:1077
+0x6ae
createdbygoogle.golang.org/grpc.(*addrConn).connect
/home/dingrui/go/pkg/mod/google.golang.org/grpc@v1.24.0/clientconn.go:743
+0x122
goroutine43[IOwait]:
internal/poll.runtime_pollWait(0x7ffff7f48dd8,0x72,0xffffffffffffffff)
/usr/local/go/src/runtime/netpoll.go:184+0x57
internal/poll.(*pollDesc).wait(0xc00024e198,0x72,0x8000,0x8000,
0xffffffffffffffff)
/usr/local/go/src/internal/poll/fd_poll_runtime.go:87+0x47
internal/poll.(*pollDesc).waitRead(...)
/usr/local/go/src/internal/poll/fd_poll_runtime.go:92
internal/poll.(*FD).Read(0xc00024e180,0xc000256000,0x8000,0x8000,0x0,0x0,0x0)
/usr/local/go/src/internal/poll/fd_unix.go:169+0x1d1
net.(*netFD).Read(0xc00024e180,0xc000256000,0x8000,0x8000,0x0,0x800010601,0x0)
/usr/local/go/src/net/fd_unix.go:202+0x51
net.(*conn).Read(0xc0001720c8,0xc000256000,0x8000,0x8000,0x0,0x0,0x0)
/usr/local/go/src/net/net.go:184+0x6a
```

```
dingrui@dingrui-PC:~$ go version
go version go1.13.1 linux/amd64
dingrui@dingrui-PC:~$ go env
GO111MODULE=""
GOARCH="amd64"
GOBIN=""
GOCACHE="/home/dingrui/.cache/go-build"
GOENV="/home/dingrui/.config/go/env"
GOEXE=""
GOFLAGS=""
GOHOSTARCH="amd64"
GOHOSTOS="linux"
GONOPROXY=""
GONOSUMDB=""
GOOS="linux"
GOPATH="/home/dingrui/go"
GOPRIVATE=""
GOPROXY="https://goproxy.cn,direct"
GOROOT="/usr/local/go"
GOSUMDB="sum.golang.org"
GOTMPDIR=""
GOTOOLDIR="/usr/local/go/pkg/tool/linux_amd64"
GCCGO="gccgo"
AR="ar"
CC="gcc"
CXX="g++"
CGO_ENABLED="1"
GOMOD=""
CGO_CFLAGS="-g -O2"
CGO_CPPFLAGS=""
CGO_CXXFLAGS="-g -O2"
CGO_FFLAGS="-g -O2"
CGO_LDFLAGS="-g -O2"
PKG_CONFIG="pkg-config"
GOGCCFLAGS="-fPIC -m64 -pthread -fmessage-length=0 -fdebug-prefix-map=/tmp/go-build180008548=/tmp/go-build -gno-record-gcc-switches"
```

Answer (score 1):

I would read this section of the Go documentation on `signal` very carefully

https://pkg.go.dev/os/signal#hdr-Go_programs_that_use_cgo_or_SWIG

Particularly this statement

> If the non-Go code installs any signal handlers, it must use the `SA_ONSTACK` flag with sigaction. Failing to do so is likely to cause the program to crash if the signal is received. Go programs routinely run with a limited stack, and therefore set up an alternate signal stack.

Presumably you are using CGo to integrate into that C library.  If the C code installs signal handlers, you may get this problem.

To solve it, you may want to write a small C function, and call it before your Go code will make any system calls.  It would add the SA_ONSTACK flag to the signal handler, perhaps as follows:

```
 void set_signal_sa_onstack() {
     struct sigaction action;
     struct sigaction old_action;
     sigaction(SIGCHLD, NULL, &action);
     action.sa_flags = action.sa_flags | SA_ONSTACK;
     sigaction(SIGCHLD, &action, &old_action);
 }
```